# Why won't the for loop execute on directory

Tags: bash, for

In the following script, the first **for** loop executes as expected, but not the second. I do not get any error, it seems that the script just hangs.

```
HOME=/root/mydir

DIR=$HOME/var
DIRWORK=$HOME/Local

for f in $(find $DIR -type f); do

    lsof -n $f | grep [a-z] > /dev/null

    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "hi"       
    fi
done


for i in $(find $DIRWORK -type d -name work); do
    echo "2"
done
```

Comment: What does the find command in the second loop returns?

Comment: How long does it take the `find` command to finish? Until then the script "hangs", of course. Even if `find` doesn't find anything.

Comment: Looks like the script took much longer than expected in case of second for loop. The first for loop was echoing output pretty fast, but not the second. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Thought: There is nothing wrong with your script and you are not experiencing any problems. You just feel your script should behave differently, for reasons you are not telling us.

Comment: @user1129682 : I was not able to understand why the second for loop was taking longer than expected. But cleared after reading the answer from lesmana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is coded in a dangerous way.

First, I assume you are using the Bash shell since you tagged it '/bash' and '/for'.

In my answer I will quote this great [Bash guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), which is probably the best source to learn Bash from out there.

**1)** Never use a [Command Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution), of **either** kind, without quotes. There is a major issue here: using an unquoted expansion to split output into arguments.

Specifically speaking, this `$(find $DIRWORK -type d -name work)` and `$(find $DIR -type f)`  will undergo [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), thus if `find` finds a file with spaces in its name, i.e. "file name", the word splitting result of Bash will pass 2 argument for the `for` command to iterate over, i.e. one for "file" and one for "name". In this case you want to hope that you'll get a "file: No such file or directory" and "name: No such file or directory", instead of potentially causing damage to them if they truly exist.

**2)** By convention, environment variables (PATH, EDITOR, SHELL, ...) and internal shell variables (BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Your $DIRWORK directory breaks that convention, and it also unquoted, thus if we let `DIRWORK='/path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2'`, `find` will look into two different directories when $DIRWORK is unquoted. The subject of using quotes is very important in Bash, so you should "Double quote" **every** expansion, as well as anything that could possibly contain a special character, e.g. "$var", "$@", "${array[@]}", "$(command)". Bash treats everything within 'single quotes' as literal. Learn the difference between ' and " and `. See [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), [Arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments) and you might also want to take a look at this link: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

This is a safer version of your script, which I recommend you to use instead:

```
my_home="/root/mydir"

my_dir="$my_home/var"
dir_work="$my_home/Local"

while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    # I'm guessing that you also want to ignore stderr;
    # this is where the 2>&1 came from.
    if lsof -n "$f" | grep '[a-z]' > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "hey, I'm safer now!"
    fi
done < <(find "$dir_work" -type f -print0)


while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    echo "2"
done < <(find "$dir_work" -type d -name 'work' -print0)
```

As you can see, the `IFS` variable is set to be emtpy, thus preventing `read` from trimming leading and trailing spaces from a line. The `read` command uses an empty string ( `-d ''` ) as a delimiter, to read until it reaches a \0.
`find` needs to be modified accordingly, therefore it uses the `-print0` option to delimit its data with a \0 instead of a new line - which, amazingly and maliciously, can be a part of a file name. Splitting such a file by \n into two pieces will break our code.

You might want to read about [Process Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) if you don't understand my script completely.

The previous answer which stated that `find ... | while read name; do ...; done` should be used for reading `find`s output can be also bad.
The `while` loop above is executed in a new subshell with its own copy of variables copied from the parent. This copy then is used for whatever you like. When the `while` loop is finished, the subshell copy is discarded, and the original variables of the parent did not change.

If you aim on modifying some variables inside this `while` loop and use them afterwards in the parent, consider using the safer script above which will prevent data loss.

Comment: "Never use a Command Substitution, of either kind, without quotes." This is just nitpicking, but it's okay to use command substitution without quotes when you're setting a variable: `something=$(basename "filename with spaces")`.

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
for i in $(find $DIRWORK -type d -name work); do
    echo "2"
done
```

will first execute this line

```
find $DIRWORK -type d -name work
```

wait until `find` finished executing and then take the output and put it back in the `for` loop

```
for i in the output of find; do
    echo "2"
done
```

only then the for loop will start executing.

So if the `find` is taking a long time to finish the `for` loop has to wait a long time before it can start.

Try timing the `find` command in an interactive prompt

```
$ time find $DIRWORK -type d -name work
```

and see how long that takes.

---

Also note: you shouldn't use a `for` loop to loop over filenames. Use a `while` loop with `read` like this:

```
find $DIRWORK -type d -name work | while read name; do
    echo "2"
done
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748703/iterate-over-lines-instead-of-words-in-a-for-loop-of-shell-script/10752407#10752407) for more information.

Bonus: this executes the `while` loop in parallel to `find`. That means the `while` loop will execute one iteration as soon as `find` prints out one line. It does not have to wait for `find` to finish executing.